# Laravel - File Uploading issues using a virtual host

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4, virtualhost

I have a problem regarding uploading a file to my server with laravel in a virtual host.

Here's the case: when I try to upload an have a link to the absolute path like this:

```
if ($file->move( 'laravel.dev/upload', $file->getClientOriginalName() )) {
                    echo 'uploaded';
                }
```

The file can be uploaded successsfully though it will create a folder named "laravel.dev" which is my host and inside of it creates another folder named "upload". On the other side, If I set my code like this:

```
if ($file->move( asset('uploaded'), $file->getClientOriginalName() )) {
                    echo 'uploaded';
                }
```

It throws this error:
[image: Laravel Error]

What I wanted to achieve is to upload the file directly to the "upload" folder I created in "projectname/public/" public folder. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead.

```
$var = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads';

if ( $file->move($var, $file->getClientOriginalName()) ) {
    echo 'uploaded';
}
```

You use path not URLs like `laravel.dev/upload`.

Answer (score 0):

As Juan posted, you are using url paths instead of file paths. Laravel have some [path helpers](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#paths) to help you with this problem.

If you would want to select a folder like `public/uploaded` you can use `public_path().'/uploaded`.
If you would want to selected a folder like `app/storage/uploaded` you can use `storage_path().'/uploaded`.

In your example you can use this code:

```
if ($file->move( public_path().'/uploaded', $file->getClientOriginalName() )) {
    echo 'uploaded';
}
```